# How to make racket the default implementation for geiser mode

Tags: repl, scheme

The geiser documentation suggests that setting `geiser-default-implementation` is one way to prevent `run-geiser` from prompting for a scheme implementation. Another approach suggested by the geiser docs is to set the `geiser-implementations-alist` to the following value:

```
(((regexp "\\.scm\\'") guile)
 ((regexp "\\.ss\\'") racket)
 ((regexp "\\.rkt\\'") racket))
```

In neither case do the docs give examples of how to set. I've tried various incantations involving `setq`, `defcustom`, etc., but I continue to be prompted for the desired scheme implementation whenever I run `run-geiser`. The alist doesn't even evaluate properly: for one thing, the regexp function seems not to exist; for another, I'm thinking some sort of quoting is needed to prevent errors on the undefined guile/racket symbols. Would be grateful if someone could give an example of exactly what would need to be added (e.g.) to .emacs in both cases.

Would also like to understand why something like...

```
(setq geiser-default-implementation 'racket)
```

...doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Type "racket" in the command-line when it asks you for the implementation.